# How to create the vector which contains products of t and t-1 elements, which belong to another vector?

Tags: r, vector, multiplication

I am new to R and I am struggling with some basic issues.
I have a vector X counting 1950 values (i=1,2,...,1950). I would like to make vector Y in such way that Yi = Xi*Xi-1 (product of 2 neighbor elements from vector X).
I understand that the vector Y will have one less observation than vector X.

For example if mu vector X is as follows, how would I make the vector Y?

Thank you for any assistance that you can provide.

```
X    
1.0019502
1.0002979
1.0007346
1.0007341
0.9999603
1.0035292
1.0003161
1.0001975
0.9996051
1.000158
0.9981829
0.9999604
1.0014841
0.9987947
0.9992878
1.0002376
1.0002573
0.9995251
0.9995249
1.0001783
1.0003564
1.0008116
0.9998418
1.0016419
1.0007702
1.0007302
1.0006113
0.9998818
0.9999409
0.9974572
0.9983202
1.0014846
0.9999802
0.9983199
1.0012474
1.0004153
1.0001977
0.9997628
0.999664
0.9982203
1.0005547
0.9994456
1.0008716
0.9997625
0.9993071
0.9994453
0.9982755
0.999444
0.9977352
1.0001593
1.0008163
0.9985876
1.0017132
1.0001193
0.9976934
1.0010962
1.0003185
1.0013931
1.000795
1.0000993
1.0003177
0.999861
1.0008537
1.0005356
1.000456
0.9998613
0.9992865
0.999167
1.0011513
1.0003767
1.0001387
1.000218
0.9997226
1.0005549
1.0001386
1.0001188
0.9998416
0.9984552
0.9998413
1.0007142
0.999207
1.0001786
0.9988891
1.0004369
1.0011315
0.9997621
1.000238
1.0008129
0.9995245
1.0008721
0.9985345
1.0006148
1.0000793
1.0001784
0.998494
0.9998809
1.0001786
1.0001389
0.9994444
1.0010919
0.9991076
1.0010718
0.9991078
0.9987101
0.9984501
1.0002587
1.0006367
1.0009544
1.0000795
1.0001192
0.9994836
1.0009141
1.0001787
0.9998809
1.0005956
1.0007341
1.0002379
0.9994054
0.9998612
1.0004562
1.001031
0.9994058
1.0004162
0.9998811
0.9997424
0.9998018
1.0003766
1.0002179
1.0000396
0.9999604
0.9998019
1.0001585
0.9991482
0.9992664
0.9995833
0.9997618
0.9991661
1.0007154
1.0003177
1.0006551
0.9997024
0.9997024
1.0014688
0.9992468
0.9990479
1
1.0002978
1.0002977
1.0001191
0.9994048
1.0000199
0.9993052
1.0008741
0.9992259
0.999563
1.0009737
1.0003176
0.9997817
1.0004566
0.9989484
0.9999801
1
0.9998411
1.0007152
0.9997221
0.9982923
1.0017106
0.9981732
0.9995226
0.9992238
1.0000598
1.0002589
1.0008363
1.0006565
1.000338
1.0000398
1.000477
0.9999205
1.0002185
1.0002185
1.0003574
0.9996625
1.0000199
0.9997021
1.0002185
0.9991461
0.9996224
0.9995029
0.9999801
1.0010544
0.999841
1.0002186
0.999543
0.9998211
0.9993438
0.9996418
0.9999602
1.0003185
0.9999602
1.0001791
0.9995424
1.0000199
1.0005772
1.0001393
0.9998807
0.9989855
0.9994026
1.0001395
0.9998008
1.000279
1.0002988
1.0003186
0.9990245
0.9998007
1.0002392
1.0001993
0.9965732
1.0007197
0.9997803
1.0004995
1.0002197
1.0014576
1.0000798
0.9995813
0.9995213
1.0003991
0.9993218
1.0000399
0.9994611
1.0007988
0.9995411
1.000539
1.0000998
0.9992618
0.9996606
0.9994807
1.0006994
0.9998403
1.0003595
0.9996606
1.0004593
1.0011578
1.0001595
0.9998006
0.9994816
0.9998803
0.9994214
0.9998802
0.9998602
1
1.0007988
1.0003991
0.9995413
1.0001995
0.999581
0.9987426
1.0011591
1.0001397
1.0000599
0.9994412
1.0010783
1.000359
1.0005583
1.0001395
1.0005978
0.999303
1.0001993
0.9988843
1.0000399
0.9998803
0.9997407
1.0000599
0.9999202
1.0008979
0.9995415
1.0002194
1.0001196
0.9999203
1.0001396
1.0004785
0.9999004
0.9993424
1.0000598
1.0003589
0.9998804
1.0006379
1.0000598
0.9998008
1.0003587
0.9991236
1.0000199
1.000319
0.9989039
1.0004589
1.0002194
0.9996012
0.9997806
1.0004589
1.0001396
0.9996212
0.9993218
1.0000599
0.9993015
0.9994008
1.0000999
0.9994605
1.0008397
0.9995605
1.0008194
0.9996805
0.9997403
1.0001199
0.9998202
1.0001798
0.9998402
1.00004
0.9998801
1.0004396
0.9997803
0.99996
0.9996604
0.9996403
1.0002799
0.9992005
1.0006601
0.9998401
0.9997601
0.99956
0.9995799
1.0003603
0.9993397
1.0004204
1.0000801
1.0005203
1.00026
0.9994201
1.0005802
0.9999
0.99996
0.9997
0.9994799
1.0005404
1.0011602
1.0004596
1.0001997
0.9998602
1.0002996
0.9998602
0.9994209
0.9998601
1.00002
0.9998402
1.00002
1.0006195
1.0002596
1.0010782
1.0003391
1.0002791
0.999701
0.9999801
0.9999601
0.9998205
0.9994416
0.9998005
1.0001996
0.9996608
0.9998603
0.9992414
1.0008391
0.9996606
1.00002
0.9996805
1.0006392
1.0000399
0.9995808
0.9995407
0.9999201
0.9993207
1
0.9995001
0.9995399
1.0003202
1.0007203
1.0008997
1.0006592
0.9999002
0.9993412
1.0014383
1.0006583
1.0095489
0.9997828
1.0006123
0.9980261
0.9987342
0.9998218
0.9994652
0.9998018
1.0004955
1.0007132
1.0001188
0.997783
0.9974805
1.0013723
1.001291
1.0002777
0.9994448
1.0009921
1.0009514
1.0001584
0.9998812
1.0009307
0.9986547
1.0008122
1.0007324
1.0016022
1.0004147
1.0005922
1
1.0003157
1.0001775
1.0010056
0.9989363
0.9997831
0.9989349
1.0006911
1.0003946
0.9995069
1.0000789
1.0000197
1.0002762
1.0006115
0.9993297
0.9999408
0.9994871
1.0003553
0.9999013
0.9998816
0.9998026
1.0002961
0.999704
0.9970983
0.9990497
1.0005945
0.9995643
1.0008519
0.9997625
0.9992278
1.0005152
1.0004555
1.0001386
1
1.0011876
0.9998814
1
1.0002966
0.9986954
1.0005542
0.999545
1.000752
1.0001582
1.0001582
0.9998814
1.000257
0.9991303
1.0005144
0.9994463
0.9989316
1.0005546
0.9996437
1.0000594
1.0000792
0.9997624
0.9994653
0.9998415
1.0001982
1.0009312
0.9997625
1.0001782
0.9999406
0.9999604
1.0006929
1.0017806
0.9991705
1.0009883
1
0.9997828
1.0013628
1.0001578
1.000355
0.999862
1.0000394
0.9996648
1.0001972
1.0008873
1.0002364
0.9993894
1.0005715
1.0000788
0.9996061
0.9998227
1.0001182
1.0001379
1.0006502
1.0003544
0.9992718
1.0003348
0.9981492
1.0017754
0.9998622
0.9991138
1.000276
0.9994876
1.0003943
1.0001774
1.0007882
1.0004332
0.9996261
1.0001969
1.0000984
1.0004724
0.9996262
1.000059
1.0002362
1.0005312
1.0001573
0.9996461
0.9999017
1.0004327
1.0003146
0.9992728
1.000177
0.9998623
0.9995673
0.9999606
1.0001181
1.0005509
1.0007473
1.0000393
1.0005698
0.9995876
1.0000786
1.0001964
0.9999018
0.9997054
0.9994695
1.0002556
0.9995676
0.9994888
1.0005902
1.0004129
1
1.0004324
1.0002554
1.0002357
0.9998037
1.0000786
1.0001375
0.9996662
1.0000589
0.9997447
0.9999804
0.9996071
1.0004324
0.9999411
1.0002357
0.9996465
1.0002358
1.0000196
0.9999214
0.9998428
1.0000589
1
0.9998035
1.0003341
0.9997643
0.9997839
1.0001179
0.9999017
1.0002555
1.0002161
0.9995875
1.0004323
1
1.0002554
0.9998036
0.9999607
1.0000786
0.9998625
0.9999607
0.9998232
0.9998821
1.0002358
0.9999411
0.9998625
0.9999214
1.0001572
0.9998625
0.999941
1.0001376
1
1.0002358
1.0000393
1.0003339
0.999568
1.000275
1.0001178
0.9998036
0.9998625
0.9998821
1.0001179
0.9996857
0.9998035
0.9998624
0.9997051
0.9994494
1.000118
1.0001377
1.0004327
1.0000197
1.0002359
0.9997641
1.0003539
1.0003734
0.999725
0.9993712
1.0004129
1.0002359
0.9994301
0.9995478
1.0008655
0.9999607
1.0001376
1.0002358
1.0000589
0.9999411
1.0000589
0.9991552
1.0008848
0.9996464
0.9998231
1.0003734
0.9998232
1.0003537
0.9996268
0.9993515
1.0004719
0.9997445
1.0001573
0.9996658
0.9990365
0.9998032
0.9986219
1.0007688
1.0005122
0.9995865
0.9999803
0.9998424
0.9999409
0.9998424
0.9997438
0.9997438
1.0000591
1.000414
1.0004138
0.9996258
0.9994483
1.0000591
1.0001774
1.0010841
0.9993699
1.0004925
1.0006105
0.9998032
1.0003346
0.9996655
0.9998032
0.9999212
0.9998228
1.0001378
0.9998622
1.0007877
1.0004723
0.999292
1.0004724
0.9995672
1.0006298
0.999705
0.9996655
1.0005511
0.9997049
1.0000984
0.9995081
1.0006299
0.9995869
1.0002362
1.0000984
1.0000393
0.9995082
1.0001378
1.0003149
1.0005115
1.0002163
0.9999017
0.9998034
1.0005113
1.0000983
0.9996266
0.9999017
0.999823
1.000295
1.0001376
0.9999803
1.0004325
0.9997249
0.9997838
0.9997248
0.9999607
1.0004916
1.0002162
1.0002162
0.9999018
0.9997053
0.9998035
1.000059
0.9996462
1.0002163
0.9999017
1.0002949
0.9997641
1.0001769
0.9998427
1.000118
1.000059
1.0000983
0.9996855
0.9991153
1.0002558
1.0006492
0.9997248
1.0001573
1.0000197
0.999882
0.9999607
0.9996067
0.9997443
0.9994884
0.9998819
0.9993108
0.9997833
1.0003153
1.0008669
0.999685
1.0001969
0.9999606
1.0003938
1.0000787
1.0002361
0.9996655
0.9998229
1.0002362
0.9999606
1.0004133
1.0002754
0.999764
1.0001967
1.0004524
0.9994102
1.000059
1
0.9994296
1.000492
1.0001377
1
1.0000983
1.0003147
1.0000197
1.0002163
0.9997052
1.0003342
0.9980346
1.0002166
1.0015948
0.9988009
1.0006692
1.0034616
1.000392
0.9987657
1.0009808
1.0008819
0.9986294
0.9993922
1.0003728
1.0001961
1.0004314
0.9994904
1.0006471
1.0004507
0.9990794
0.9989413
0.9996663
0.9996073
0.9995875
0.9998232
1.000963
1.0004319
0.9989599
0.9997053
1.0005502
0.9997054
1.0025737
1.0010386
1.0008222
1.0002934
0.9999022
1.0004107
1.0006842
1.0001172
1.0000586
0.9990039
0.9999413
0.9979666
1.0004114
1.0001175
0.9995496
0.9988442
1.0003922
0.9992942
0.9996665
0.9989991
1.0005304
0.9996662
1.0003143
0.9996269
0.9981733
1.0002165
1.0010034
1.0008058
0.9996269
1.0011984
0.9990581
0.9995483
1.0000196
1.0013754
1.001452
1.0009797
0.9983753
1.001098
0.99953
0.999471
1.0010194
1.0000783
0.999765
1.0001567
0.9996279
1
0.9997061
0.9990789
1.0007258
0.9998236
0.9994707
1.0003531
1.0004118
1.0003136
0.9989615
1.0006277
1.0004508
1.0005486
0.9989425
1.0006469
1.0003722
0.9989033
1.0002353
1.0001764
0.9996473
0.9998236
1.0005882
1.0002156
0.9999804
0.9992947
1.0003333
1.0005292
0.9993928
1.0000784
1.00049
1.0001763
0.9994516
1.0000392
1.0001372
0.9994906
1.0009017
1.0001175
0.999765
1.0001959
0.9992166
1.0003332
1.0010384
1.0001957
1.0010176
0.9998436
1.0001955
0.9993158
1.0000978
0.9999804
1.0001956
0.9998436
1.0004107
0.9998827
0.9998045
1.0000782
1.0000782
1.0000391
1.0006257
0.9992184
1.0003129
1.000391
1.0008013
1.0000195
1.0005467
1.0001366
1.0005464
1.0001755
0.9997075
0.9994734
1.0004098
1.0003511
1.0003705
0.9998246
1.0004679
0.9999805
1.0004287
0.9999416
1.0002922
1.0004674
1.0007786
1.0005057
0.9994945
0.9997082
0.999786
0.9996886
0.9993965
1.0001558
0.9994742
1.0003702
1.0007402
0.9992604
1.0001753
1.0001363
1.0002726
1.0007008
0.9998249
1.0005059
1.0002723
0.9999806
0.9999222
0.9993973
1.0003696
0.9990276
0.9999027
0.9992407
1.0004286
1.0002337
1.0002921
0.9999611
1.0000584
0.9997275
0.9998637
0.9999805
0.9999416
0.9998442
1.000818
0.9999222
1.0001946
0.9999027
1.0001362
1.0002335
0.9996109
0.9998832
1.0000389
1.0001362
0.9999805
1.0002335
1.0006226
0.9997278
0.9999611
0.9999222
1.0002723
0.999475
0.9999027
1.0003308
1.0000389
0.9999222
1.0000389
1.0004085
1.0003694
0.9996307
1.0001944
0.9998639
1.0002333
1.0001944
0.9997862
0.9999222
1.0002333
0.9998251
1.0001361
1.0004859
1.0002525
0.9992814
1.0001166
0.9998057
1.0002332
0.9995725
0.9999028
1
1.0000389
0.9996695
0.9996499
1.0000195
1.0001946
1.0000973
1.0003306
1.0002722
0.9997862
1
0.9999028
0.9999806
0.9996111
1.0003112
1.0001167
1.0006805
0.9998251
1.0003109
0.9995726
1.0000194
0.9994169
1.0000389
1.0000194
1.0004667
0.9995335
0.9997083
1.0004668
1.0002528
0.9999611
0.9999222
0.9996306
1.0004862
1.0005054
1.0005245
0.9996699
0.9999417
0.9991453
1.0006416
1
1.0007383
0.9994952
0.999495
1.0001943
0.9988147
1.0001945
1.0009919
0.9991839
0.9998833
1.0000972
0.9994166
1.000253
1.0000195
1.0000778
0.9999222
0.9999611
0.9998249
1.0001362
1.0001362
1.0007586
0.9998445
1
1.0000583
1.0001944
0.9995141
1.0005639
0.9995725
0.9997473
1.000564
1.0006803
0.9999417
0.9997669
0.9995337
0.9995918
0.9999806
0.9996111
1.0004085
1.0000778
0.9997472
1.0000972
0.9998055
1.0003112
0.9999222
0.9997472
1.0003696
0.9997472
1.0004668
1.000175
0.9992225
1.0000389
0.9997277
1.0003308
0.9999222
0.9989302
0.9998053
1.0001363
1.0000389
1
1.0003505
0.9997469
0.9995911
0.9994351
1.0009745
1.0001752
0.9993771
1.0008571
1.0005255
0.9998444
1.0003502
0.9997472
1.0004474
0.99965
0.9996693
1.0003502
0.9995526
1.0001946
1.0001556
1.0000389
1.0001362
0.9999806
1.0001945
0.9997083
1.0000389
1.000389
0.9997861
0.9999222
0.9998639
0.9998444
1.0000584
1.0001556
1.0003696
0.9997667
0.9996499
1.000214
0.9996693
0.9999027
1.0000973
1.0000973
0.9999027
0.9998054
1.0001946
0.999786
1.0000778
1.0003697
0.9996304
1.0002335
0.9995525
0.9995329
0.99963
0.999552
0.9994153
0.999844
1.0000585
0.999883
1.0001755
0.999649
1
0.9978346
1.0007234
0.9999023
1.0009378
0.9993168
0.9968356
1.0003723
0.9992752
1.0005881
1.0010775
1.0005088
1.0004303
0.9999022
0.9989246
1.0000391
0.9999804
0.9993149
0.9984134
1.0004708
0.9980979
1.001945
0.9988431
0.9997841
0.9994109
1.0000393
1.0003536
0.9998036
0.9996857
0.9991354
1.0002557
0.9992922
0.9996655
1
1.0000787
1.0021451
0.9999804
0.999568
0.9999214
1.0020631
1.0001765
0.9999804
1.0009998
1.0007051
1
1.0006654
0.9988656
0.9993343
1.0005094
1.0003721
0.9989233
0.9999412
0.9998236
0.9999608
1.0009017
1.0004309
1.0005481
0.9995108
1.0002741
1.0007437
1.0000587
0.9997849
1.0002151
1.0007626
1.0005666
1.0003906
1.000488
1.0001561
1.0004487
1.000819
1.0000779
1.0002143
0.9997078
0.9997467
1.0000974
0.9995128
1.0004289
0.9994154
1.000195
0.999805
1.000156
1.0006629
0.9996883
0.999961
1
0.9996297
1.0010334
0.9989482
1.000312
0.9996492
1.0000585
0.9999805
1
1.0001365
0.9990837
0.9991024
1.0000195
1.0008007
1.0000195
1.000683
0.999922
1
0.9998245
0.9995319
1.0000195
1.0000585
0.999239
1.0001562
1.0001953
1.0003319
0.9999415
1.0002927
0.9995903
1.0008783
0.999766
1.0003121
1.0001365
0.9992201
1.0006439
0.9994345
1.0003512
1.0000195
0.9999415
1.0005656
0.9998441
1.0000585
1.0003509
0.9998831
1.0001364
0.9999415
0.9998051
1.0002729
0.9998246
1.0000975
1.0001949
1
1
0.9999221
0.9999415
0.9999415
1.0001754
0.9998441
0.9994348
1.0004095
0.9992983
0.9997269
0.9997464
0.9996292
0.9997852
1.0003124
1.000039
1.0002342
1.000039
0.9998634
1.0001757
1.000039
1.0001561
1
1.0002341
1.000078
1.0001365
1.0000585
1.000039
0.9993565
0.9998244
0.9994926
1.0005272
1.0000976
0.9997073
1.0002342
0.9998829
0.999961
0.9999414
1.0002147
0.9999415
0.9997073
1.0001367
0.9995511
1.0000781
1.0001757
0.9999414
0.9998243
0.9997657
0.9998047
0.9998632
0.9999609
0.9999609
0.9999609
1.0002931
1.0003907
1.0000781
0.9999219
1
1.0003905
1.0002342
0.9996097
1.0002928
0.9999805
0.9998048
0.9997072
1.0002734
1.0001562
0.9998439
1.0002343
0.9998634
1.0001366
1.0001757
1.0003122
0.9997074
0.9999024
0.9995902
1.0006247
1.0001366
0.9995123
1.0002733
1.0000195
1.0000195
0.9999805
1.0001951
0.9997854
1
0.9998634
1.0003122
1.0000975
0.9996684
1.0001756
0.9997464
1.0002342
1.0000976
0.9994928
0.9999024
1.0004099
1.0000781
0.9999805
0.9996098
1.0001366
1.0001366
0.999961
1.0003513
0.9999805
0.9997074
1.0002927
1.0000975
1.000078
1.0002341
0.999805
0.9997074
1.0002926
1
0.9995319
1.0005073
1.000039
1.0001755
0.999922
1.0000585
1.0001755
1.0000975
1.0001949
0.999922
0.9999805
1.0000975
0.9999025
0.9999025
0.9998635
1.000078
1
0.9998635
1.0000975
1.000195
1
0.9997856
0.999883
1.0002145
0.999922
1.000078
1.0001754
1.000078
1.0000974
1.0003118
0.9999416
1.0001169
0.9998636
1.0001948
0.9992014
0.999961
1.0002534
0.9997466
1.0003899
0.999961
1.0002534
0.9994934
1.000078
1.0002924
0.9999221
0.9998636
1.0004093
1.0001948
0.9996104
1.0002728
0.9998831
1.000039
1.0002338
0.9999026
0.9998636
1.000039
0.9997273
1.0000779
0.9999415
1.0002144
0.9999416
0.9997857
0.999922
1.0002339
0.9998636
1.0000779
0.9996882
1.0002729
0.9997077
0.999961
0.9993372
1.0004877
0.999883
1.000234
1
1.0001365
0.9996102
0.9999805
1.000117
0.9998635
1.0003705
1.0004483
0.9999026
0.9998636
1.000078
0.9998246
1.0001364
1.0001559
0.9999221
0.9996492
1.0003509
0.9998636
0.9995518
1.0000975
0.999961
0.9996296
0.9992589
1.0001171
0.9995121
1.0000195
1.0003319
0.9998634
1.0002147
0.9999805
1.0000195
1.000039
1.0001171
1.0003903
0.999883
0.9998634
1.0001366
1.0000585
1.000078
1.0000585
0.9997659
1.0001366
1.0001756
0.9997465
1.0000975
1.0002146
0.999727
1.0004292
1.0000975
1.000234
0.9999415
1.0003509
1
1
1.0001559
0.9995519
0.9996686
1.000078
1.0001365
1.000039
1.0000585
1.0000585
0.9999415
1.000078
1.0000585
0.9999415
0.9996881
0.9991616
1.0160211
1.0009411
1.0002494
0.9992518
0.9981954
1.0018079
1.0016894
0.9986776
1.0003838
1.0003645
0.9998466
1.000959
0.9996551
1.0003642
0.9996168
0.9990033
0.9992517
0.9995968
1.0004034
1.0006721
0.9986376
0.9994043
0.9990002
1.0001155
1.0008082
1.0004422
1.0002691
1.0000192
0.9995004
1.000173
1.0004421
1.0007685
0.9998848
0.9999808
0.9998848
0.9999232
0.9994431
0.9990009
0.9994807
0.9996921
1
0.9997498
0.9995764
0.9992103
1.0001157
0.9991712
0.9995563
0.9998649
0.9993823
1.0009078
1.001235
1.0004047
1.0003853
1.0006162
0.9999038
1.0000192
0.9991531
0.999711
1.0010213
0.9997113
0.9996342
1.0002119
1.0004429
0.9992685
1.0002312
1.0001156
1.0003659
1.0004042
1.0004233
0.9998269
0.9993075
0.999307
0.999634
0.999499
1
1.0000771
1.0002892
1.0000964
0.9997495
1.0004434
1.0001927
0.9998459
1
1.0001156
1.0002119
0.9998844
1.0005394
0.9999037
0.9999615
1.0002118
0.9998845
0.9992299
0.9998266
0.9996146
0.9995373
1.0003279
1.0020438
0.9989417
1.0003467
0.999326
1.0005203
0.9994222
1.0002698
0.9998651
1.0005202
1.0003274
0.9992107
0.9998459
1.0003468
0.9998652
1.0004624
1.0002118
0.9997882
0.9993453
1.0002698
1.000366
1.0002118
0.9999422
1.0010012
1.00025
0.9998846
1.0003462
1.0000961
0.999827
0.9998462
1.0001731
1.0000192
1.0001923
1.0005959
0.9996734
1.0000384
1.0001537
1.0000576
0.9997887
0.9999616
1.0002883
1.0000961
1.0007108
0.9998272
0.9999232
1
1.0001344
1.000288
1.0001343
1.0004606
0.9998465
0.9998657
1.0002686
1.0004028
1.0001342
0.9998658
1.0001917
1.0002684
1.0001725
0.9996168
0.9999617
0.9995591
0.9999616
0.9991753
1.0001344
0.9998465
1.0004607
1.0000576
0.9999616
1.0000959
1.0001151
1.0002494
1.000211
1.0004602
1.0001533
0.9999425
1
1.0000958
1.0001533
1.0002299
1.0006321
1.0002297
1.0001722
1.0001339
0.9996556
1.0004019
1.000153
0.9999044
0.99956
0.9995981
0.9999617
0.9998468
0.9990617
1.0001917
1.0004599
1.0003448
1.0002489
1.0002871
0.9996938
0.9999617
1.0001723
0.9998086
0.9999809
0.9997894
0.9995979
0.9999617
1.0000766
1.0003831
1.0000574
0.9995405
0.9998659
0.9994827
0.9995016
1.0000575
0.9996548
1.000422
1
1.0003068
0.9995208
1.0000384
1.0004603
0.9997508
1.0001342
0.9998658
1.0004027
1.0009391
0.999617
0.9999617
0.9998851
0.9998276
1.0001533
1.0000192
1.0000766
0.9997893
1
1.0001341
1.0000383
0.9998467
0.9999425
0.999885
0.9997509
1.0002492
0.9997317
0.9997508
0.9998274
0.9994247
0.9996162
1.0000192
1.0001152
0.9999424
0.9999424
0.9999808
0.9996545
1.0002112
0.9997504
1.0012674
1.0002685
0.9999425
1.0000192
1.0000959
1.0003451
0.9997508
0.9997508
0.9996165
0.9996355
1.0002878
1.0001343
1.0004795
1
0.9994823
1.0000959
1.0002685
1.0001726
1.0001725
0.9994824
0.9999808
1.0003452
0.9998658
1.0000192
0.9999808
0.9999041
0.9995973
0.9999233
0.9998465
0.9999616
1.0005949
1.0003836
0.9997124
0.9996356
0.9998849
1.0003262
1.0004028
0.9997699
0.9998466
0.9998849
0.9997315
1.0005948
1.0000192
0.9999041
1.0000959
0.9997699
1
0.9999808
0.9999425
1.0000767
1
1.0001534
1.0001342
1.0000575
0.9994057
0.9999808
1.0000192
0.9998849
1.0001343
0.9999424
1.0000192
1.0001151
1.0001726
0.9997699
1.0003837
1.0000384
0.9997507
1.0000575
1.0001534
0.9995781
1.0000576
0.9999233
0.9998082
0.9998849
0.9994243
0.9998656
0.9998656
0.9998848
1.0000384
0.9999616
1.0001345
1.0002497
0.9999424
1.0001152
1.000288
1.0000192
0.9994242
1.0003073
1.000192
0.9996737
0.999616
0.9999616
0.9997695
0.9998655
1.0000769
1.0004804
1
0.9997695
0.9996734
1.0002114
0.9997887
0.999827
0.9999039
1.0000577
0.9999423
1.0000961
1.000173
1.0002114
0.9999039
1.0001153
1.0000384
0.9991739
1.0001538
0.9997693
0.9999808
0.9998462
0.9997692
1.0000962
0.9999423
0.999673
1.0001539
0.9999423
0.9999615
0.9997499
1.0003657
0.9999615
1.0000962
1
0.9998653
0.9998076
0.9999423
0.9999615
1.0000385
1.0000962
1.0002694
1.0002693
0.999673
1.0002694
0.9999038
0.9998076
```

Comment: It helps to have a MINIMAL reproducible example, and show desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this helps

```
x=seq(1:5)
# x
# 1 2 3 4 5

lag_x = c(x[-1],NA)
# lag_x
# 2  3  4  5 NA
y = x * lag_x
# y
# 2  6 12 20 NA
```

Comment: I would just use `1:5` instead of `seq(1:5)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
x[-length(x)] * x[-1]
```

or

```
head(x, -1) * tail(x, -1)
```

Hope it helps,

alex